# Filling values into the next row

Tags: vba

I have a button that inputs colour, quantity and due date into a table whenever.This code works fine, but I'd like it populate the next rows below instead of overwriting the same rows each time the button is clicked

```
Sub add()

Dim Colour As Integer
Dim Quantity As Integer
Dim Duedate As Date

Colour = Range("F7").Value
Quantity = Range("H7").Value
Duedate = Range("J7").Value

Range("B14").Value = Colour
Range("C14").Value = Quantity
Range("D14").Value = Duedate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub add()
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
        .Value = ActiveSheet.Range("F7").Value
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H7").Value
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("J7").Value
    End With
End Sub
```